# Find files starting with a specific letter using find utility with -regex option

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, find

Was trying around to use the regex option on find command, without any result.

Considering this example directory "dir" that contains:

```
file1.txt 

file2.txt
Linux.txt
LInux.txt
```

So, I want for example, find all the files in dir that start with "L", and do:

```
find  dir -type f -regex ".*/^L"
```

Although this  does not produce any output. What's wrong with this?

Comment: You can't have a "beginning of line" marker in the middle of your regex ...

Comment: Remove `^` from your regex.

Comment: What would be the correct regex then?

Comment: @Cyrus that still does not work

Comment: Use `".*/L[^/]*"`

Comment: This might help: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that way works. Could you explain the [^/]* ? Why ".*/^L" would not be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.*/^L` pattern is an example of a regex that will never match any string. `^` matches start of a string position, and after a `/` there can't be any start of string.

The `find` regex pattern should match the whole string, it is *anchored* by default. So, the pattern you need is

```
.*/L[^/]*
```

It is equivalent to `^.*/L[^/]*$`: matches start of string, then any 0+ chars, up to the last `/` followed with 0 or more characters other than `/` up to the end of string. You can't use `.*` after `L` because it could match *directories* that start with `L` as `.` matches any char, and the `[^/]` negated bracket expression matches all chars but `/` and thus can't match `/`, directory separators.